How to build C extensions using free-thread python correctly?
I'm working on a C extension project which will produce a .so or .dll & .pyd file for java to load and call. A part of its function is executing given python code, so I'm trying to make it possible to execute these code in free-thread mode. I'm using Windows11 and python3.13.
The first step I took was to adapt the original code to support free-threading according to the official document.
After some code change I set Py_GIL_DISABLED=1 and executed D:\python3.13\python3.13t.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace --force to build my extension and got output.dll as expected.
In the test I loaded output.dll and python313t.dll in Java and executed import sys;print(sys.version);print(sys. _is_gil_enabled()) through my extension. The output shows that this code didn't run in free-threading mode:
3.13.0 (tags/v3.13.0:60403a5, Oct  7 2024, 09:38:07) [MSC v.1941 64 bit (AMD64)]
True

Using Dependencies on output.dll shows that output.dll depends on python313.dll, not python313t.dll which I expected.
What could be causing this issue?
Edit:
I managed to build output.dll depending on python313t.dll by adding python313t.dll to extension.libraries in setup.py.
extensions = ([
    Extension(
        ...
        libraries=get_java_libraries() + ['python313t'],  #  <-  added here
        ...),
])

The extension was build without error, but some bugs appeared during test which were off-topic.
Is this the right thing to do?
